# hg log: how to get latest commit by a particular user?

Tags: mercurial, commit

I have a repo with multiple users. I need to make a python script to retrieve a particular user's latest commits. How do I do that with mercurial?

I was thinking of calling an `hg log` command thru Python's `subprocess` call. The problem is how I should call the `hg log` command such that it tells me a user's latest logs.

Comment: What does "latest commits" mean to you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy (but not efficient or elegant way)

- `hg log -u USERNAME`

or (with revsets)

- `hg log -r "author(USERNAME)"`

with added value

> If string starts with "re:", the remainder of the string is treated as a regular expression. To match a user that actually contains "re:", use the prefix "literal:".

Comment: Maybe add links to [`hg help log`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/log), [`hg help revsets`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) and [`hg help templates`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templating) to the answer.

Comment: Also, maybe add the `-l` option to the examples (or `limit()/last()` revset functions).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to get a single user's latest commit by calling something like this with a system call.  (Command-line version follows.)

```
$ hg log -u your-user-name | head -5
```

The `head -5` gives you the whole abbreviated `hg log` output for the latest changeset for your-user-name, which includes five lines: changeset, tag, user, date, and summary.  If you want only the changeset, you could use something along these lines. (Command-line version, again.)

```
$ hg log -u mike@fontling.com | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comments suggest this makes unwarranted assumptions about the output format. I agree.

---

Based on comments, this seems to be the *best* expression for getting the last commit from a user.

```
hg log -r "last(author('email@domain.com'))" 
hg log -r "last(author('Fred Flintstone'))"
```

To get the last three . . .

```
hg log -r "last(author('email@domain.com'), 3)" 
hg log -r "last(author('Fred Flintstone'), 3)"
```

Comment: Piping is Bad Idea (tm). Templating and log options do job better in one call of log

Comment: and awk will print correctly csrt-hash **only** with redefined as ":" FS

Comment: As has been commented, *everything* you have done with piping can be done more efficiently and safely using log options. Please read up on [`hg help log`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/log), [`hg help revsets`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) and [`hg help templates`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templating).

Comment: It's not immediately obvious how those references might help return only the latest commit from a particular user. If you post an answer that does that, I'd be more than happy to upvote it. Is the safety issue not handled properly with pytyhon's pipes.quote() or shlex modules?

Comment: Look at Lazy Badger's answer to this question and my second comment there. The safety issue is that the number of lines in the text format of a changeset depends on a number of factors - any tags, bookmarks, number of parents, etc. It's not just 5 lines. It may be as few as 4, and no upper bound.

Comment: Ah, that's much more helpful. But what I wrote isn't unsafe; *unsafe* is something that exposes sensitive information through something like `ps aux`, or something that roaches the filesystem, or something that opens a security hole. What *I* wrote makes unwarranted assumptions about the output format.